# How to convert json value into array of ints [Swift]

Tags: swift

In my swift app I get this JSON: ["jsonArray": "[15,16]"] by using this code:

```
guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as? [String:String] else { return }
```

My question is: How can I convert json["jsonArray"], that is "[15,16]", into an array of ints?

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. I assume you meant `{"jsonArray": "[15,16]"}` (curly brackets at the outer level).

On top of that, it is horribly encoded. If you get a chance, get the developer on the other end to change it. In case you cannot, you can first decode it as a string, then decode it a second time to get the integers:

```
struct Response: Decodable {
    private struct RawResponse: Decodable {
        let jsonArray: String
    }

    var numbers: [Int]
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        // First decode the array as a string
        let rawResponse = try RawResponse(from: decoder)

        // Then turn it into a Data struct
        let jsonData = rawResponse.jsonArray.data(using: .utf8)!

        // And finally decode it as an Int array
        self.numbers = try JSONDecoder().decode([Int].self, from: jsonData)
    }
}

let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: json)
print(response)
```